# Insert query not working even though it is right

Tags: php, mysql, sql

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ','','','')' at line 2**

i get the above error when running my php file.

my insert query is

```
$updateUserCanvas="insert into  user_canvas(cns_id,course_id,context_id,email_id,resource_id) values(".$canvasId.",".$courseId.",'".$contextId."','".$email."','".$resourseid."')";
```

**cns_id,course_id are integer datatype and context_id,email is varchar and resource_id is text datatype**

I searched for the problem and tried adding **mysql_real_escape_string**

```
$updateUserCanvas="insert into user_canvas(cns_id,course_id,context_id,email_id,resource_id) values(".$canvasId.",".$courseId.",'".mysql_real_escape_string($contextId)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($email)."','".mysql_real_escape_string($resourseid)."')";
```

But still not working. i dont know where am mistaking.any help is greatly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: Your php vars seem to be empty `use near ','','','')`

Comment: you should use prepared statements, then you're free of worries about inverted commas and stuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
$updateUserCanvas="insert into user_canvas(cns_id,course_id,context_id,email_id,resource_id) values('".$canvasId."','".$courseId."','".addslashes($contextId)."','".addslashes($email)."','".addslashes($resourseid)."')";
```

Answer (score 0):

It's something wrong with your `$courseId`, it may be some string instead of int. Try this string:

```
$updateUserCanvas="insert into user_canvas (cns_id,course_id,context_id,email_id,resource_id) values ('{$canvasId}','{$courseId}','{$contextId}','{$email}','{$resourseid}')";
```